# How to make fancybox resizable with jqueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui, fancybox

I use fancybox to improve my image experience. To make the image resizable, I have tried to use api of jqueryUI:

```
$("#fancybox-content").resizable();
```

Sadly the .resizable() api does not work. I failed to resize fancybox.
   Any suggestion? thanks a lot.

Comment: are you using fancybox 2? if so, then use buttons helper. Check http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/#examples --> extended functionality --> button helper

Comment: @JFK I use version 1.3.4. Could button helper make fancybox resizable?

Comment: @JFK I found that the button helper could resize the fancybox to a specified size. However, what I need is to stretch to any size i want.

Comment: Sorry but the buttons helper is for fancybox v2.x only. If you upgrade, then you could use the `afterLoad` callback and the `$.extend` method to pass your new size like in http://jsfiddle.net/2XhjG/